# Flutter just_audio stopping/pausing functionality not working for my application

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, just-audio

I am trying to develop a cross-platform application that plays audio for theatrical purposes and I can play the audio, but I cannot stop it. My code in my `AudioPlayback (audio_playback.dart)` object is below for stopping the `AudioPlayer` from `just_audio`:

```dart
 Future<void> stopAudio() async {
    debugPrint("Stopping audio playback");
    await player.stop();
  }
```

I am calling stop from a different widget than the main body widget, but I do not think that should be an issue.

Here is the link to my `stop button` code: https://github.com/bgoldstone/cue_go/blob/main/lib/cue_widgets/playback_bar.dart

The stop functionality starts on line 123 and this is a `playback bar` within the application.

[image: application screenshot]

I tried wrapping the stop in the `cue_list.dart` setState function and using `async` `await` and `then`

Comment: are you sure that line 135 of your gist is generally called? also be sure you are trying to stop the same player instance that was started

Comment: I am sure. I have the Audio Player linked to a cue object, which is what populates the FutureBuilder that makes up this application. Unless the player is creating a different object, I am not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like you mess something with callback

```
final void Function(void Function()) cueListState;
```

When you tap on `IconButton` and callback `onPressed` worked, in these lines:

```
 widget.cueListState(() {
                  if (cue.player.isPlaying()) {
                    cue.player.stopAudio();
                  }
                });
```

you just throw a function at the top with this code:

```
() {
     if (cue.player.isPlaying()) {
     cue.player.stopAudio();
    }
}
```

but you don't call this piece of code:

```
if (cue.player.isPlaying()) {
     cue.player.stopAudio();
    }
```

try this:

```
onPressed: () {
          for (Cue cue in widget.cues) {
            debugPrint(
                'Cue ${cue.name} ${cue.player.isPlaying()} Playing: ${cue.player.isPlaying()}');
****************
            if (cue.player.isPlaying()) {
                cue.player.stopAudio();
              }
***************
            debugPrint("stopped cue: ${cue.cueNumber}");
            debugPrint("Cue playing: ${cue.player.isPlaying()}");
          }
        },
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. That did not work, unfortunately. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: then, if now you are trying to stop player directly in onPressed, callback is not sent up, you sure than code in onPressed is called, and it didn't work, then something wrong with cue.player